# Django 1.10 - how to change front end user authentication from username to email?

Tags: python, django, authentication

In `Django` default user authentication is integrated through `Username` and `Password`. In my project profile page, I have an option to change `Username`. So, it is necessary to change my authentication system in back end and front end with `email` and `password`.

Using [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) i can change default authentication system through `email` and `password` in admin. Here is the code -

```
class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if getattr(user, 'is_active', False) and  user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

In `settings.py` -

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'apps.account.email-auth.EmailBackend',
)
```

I was wondering how could i do the authentication through in front end. Already, I prepared front login page through `email` and `password`.

But see `form.errors` and predict must be missing any front authentication like `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what is here front end auth means ? whatever you created is appllicable for admin and client also.

Comment: can you please make it clear

Comment: Note that in django auth's `User`  the field `username` is unique, while `email` isn't. You might have to catch `MultipleObjectsReturned`, too, in `authenticate`.

Comment: To add to what @schwobaseggl said, `email` does not have database index by default, so it will also be slower.

Comment: I want to overwrite built in user authentication in login. For now, I can authenticate a user through `username` and `password`. But i want to authenticate user through `email` and `password`. Already I did that in back-end through above code. I want it to my front end login.

Answer (score 1):

Actually answer is within the method -

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
```

In front-end, naming the user input with `email` wouldn't be passed within the method then form errors show up with don't match credentials. So, simply taking input as `username` solves the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). It handles the authentication. 
It allows using 'email' and 'password' or 'username' and 'password' for authentication. It includes forms and everything else needed.
Django-cookiecutter project template uses this package to handle authentication, so you can look there and use it as a sample.